# Edit data displayed as table grid mysql php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello everyone I am displaying data from `mysql` table in a grid using php. Now I want to add a `drop down i.e select` in a column so that when the user select the value in a row it will automatically update the data in the mysql table for the current row?

Comment: please post your code!

Comment: see http://www.whathaveyoutried.com for an insight about HOW to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this on your select :

```
<select id="myId" onchange="myFunction()">
```

myFunction is a javascript function that will update your database using Ajax. You can add a parameter in "myFunction", with the current row id for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function updatedab(value)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {db: value},
        url: 'update_db.php',
        success: function(details){
            alert("done");
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```